# Android how to send data from Activity to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to pass data from my `Activity` to a `Fragment`. I have no idea how to do it. I've seen many solutions but no one of them did really work.

I just want to pass a simple `String` to the `Fragment`.

I have tried it this way:

```
public class PhotoActivty extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);
        if (null == savedInstanceState) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            String myMessage = "Stackoverflow is cool!";
            bundle.putString("message", myMessage );
            BasicFragment fragInfo = new BasicFragment();
            fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
            android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.photo_frame, fragInfo);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the error there? I call it this way:

```
String myValue = this.getArguments().getString("message");
```

In the `onCreateView` in the `Fragment`

Comment: Your code is fine. Try removing `if (null == savedInstanceState) {`

Comment: What's the error you're getting here btw?

Comment: Oh ok in portrait mode it works and in landscape it doesn't... but I think that this is due to another error. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String myMessage = "Stackoverflow is cool!";
bundle.putString("message", myMessage );
Fragment fragInfo = new BasicFragment();
fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.photo_frame, fragInfo);
transaction.commit();
```

try this inside your if

Comment: Bro you saved my time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a static factory pattern:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public static MyFragment newInstance(int index) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }
}
```

When you create the fragment in your Activity:

```
Fragment MyFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(5);
```

Alex Lockwood has a good rundown on why this is a preferred design pattern: 
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html

Answer (score 1):

from activity:

```
Bundle bundleObject = new Bundle();
bundleObject.putString("data", " Send From Activity");
/*set Fragmentclass Arguments*/
Fragment fragmentobject = new Fragment();
fragmentobject .setArguments(bundleObject );
```

From Fragment You receive this way:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
String stringText = getArguments().getString("data");    
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the real cause of the problem, but you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` inside `AppCompatActivity`. Also, classes such as `Fragment` and `FragmentTransaction` should come from `support.v4` package.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `if (null == savedInstanceState)` in your activity. If `savedInstanceStatenull == null` then `BasicFragment` will not replace your `FrameLayout` for `R.id.photo_frame`.